# production.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Prerequisite::createFileSharepoint()

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm on laravel 8.83.1.

I created a function who send three requests to create a file and upload two files on sharepoint.
I did this function on a repository class because i want later get a string to put in my requests.

I instantiate a createfile object who call createFileSharepoint at send data on my database.

My error is **production.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Prerequisite::createFileSharepoint()**

I suppose that i forgot a declaration but i don't know how declare ma function.

Constructor :

```
public function __construct(protected Prerequisite $prerequisite, protected Prerequisite $createfile)
    {
        
    }
```

My function for sharepoint:

```
public static function createFileSharepoint(){
      //requests create and upload
    }
```

Function who call createFileSharepoint:

```
public function store($request)
    {

        $prerequisite = new $this->prerequisite;

        $prerequisite->project_name = $request['project_name'];
        $prerequisite->id_user = $request['id_user'];
        $prerequisite->id_template = $request['id_template'];
        $prerequisite->kurmi_version = $request['kurmi_version'];
        $prerequisite->sharepointLink = $request['sharepointLink'];

        $prerequisite->save();

        //instance de l'objet createfil par rapport au model prequisite
        $createfile = new $this->prerequisite;
        $createfile->createFileSharepoint();

        return $prerequisite;
    }
```

My model :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Prerequisite extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'prerequisites';

     protected $fillable = ['project_name','id_user','id_template','kurmi_version','sharepointLink'];
}
```

Thanks for all your answers,
Have a nice day,

Comment: `public function __construct(protected Prerequisite $prerequisite, protected Prerequisite $createfile)
    {
        $this-prerequisite = $prerequisite;
    }`

Comment: I've got the same error